# Capistrano deployment ignore all changes made since i named my git user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I'm using capistrano to deploy a rails 3.2 app. My code is hosted on a Git server with ubuntu server. Recently i started looking in how to use more of the git features as all i was using was commit and push. Capistrano take care of taking this and deploying it in production.

The only thing unusual i did with git is the following (more people will use this git) :

```
git config --global user.name "syl"
git config --global user.email syl@my.mail.adress.com
```

Since i did that, all my new commits are ignored in the rails deployment folder by capistrano, strange thing is, if i create a clone using the command from the capistrano trace : `git clone -q linuxserveruser@gitserverip:/path/of/my/master/repo/` my latest changes are here.

What happened, what can i do to put my new commit in production?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to delete the Capistrano shared cache (and probably you moved/renamed the git repository, too.)